# Question using Timer in VB6.0

Tags: vb6

I have some query about my code, I am using VB6.0 and I have a problem using `TimerControl`. The user will first `Login[frmLogin]` and then he will be redirected to the `EmployeeForm[frmEmployee]` after the `Timer[tmLogin]/Progressbar[pgLogin]` reaches 100%.

Here is my code:

```
    Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    If Me.txtUserID.Text = "" Or Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Required field must not be a null.", vbCritical, "ERROR"
    Else
        Do Until datLogin.Recordset.EOF
            With datLogin.Recordset
                If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then

                  'Here

                Else
                    datLogin.Recordset.MoveNext
                End If
            End With
        Loop
        MsgBox "User ID and Password didn't match!", vbCritical, "ERROR LOGIN"
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is my code for `Timer`:

```
 Private Sub tmLogin_Timer()
    With Me.pbLogin
        Me.pbLogin.Value = Me.pbLogin.Value + 1
        Me.lblLoginPercent.Caption = Str(Me.pbLogin.Value) + "%"
        If Me.pbLogin.Value >= 1 And Me.pbLogin.Value < 50 Then
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Connecting..."
        ElseIf Me.pbLogin.Value >= 50 And Me.pbLogin.Value < 100 Then
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Logging in..."
        Else
            Me.lblConnecting.Caption = "Done..."
            frmLogin.Hide
            frmEmployee.Show
            Me.tmLogin.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: My problem is... I don't know how to finish this code. After the `If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then` the ProgressBar must load itself until it reaches 100%. After that, the **frmLogin.Hide** and **frmEmployee.Show** event.

Comment: When I tried this code, there's no way to stop it... What should I do sir? `If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then
                  tmLogin.Enable = True
                Else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be aware that the timer event only fires as long as there is no other processing being done in you application.

You could try to do it in the following way :

```
Private Sub cmdContinue_Click()
    Dim boolLoggedIn As Boolean

    If Me.txtUserID.Text = "" Or Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "Required field must not be a null.", vbCritical, "ERROR"
    Else
        Do Until datLogin.Recordset.EOF
            With datLogin.Recordset
                If Me.txtUserID.Text = !empid And Me.txtPassword.Text = !Password Then
                    boolLoggedIn = true
                    Exit Do
                Else
                    datLogin.Recordset.MoveNext
                End If
            End With
        Loop

        If boolLoggedIn Then 
           'While the timer is running frmLogin will still accept user
           'input, so you should disable the form to prevent that.
           'You should also consider closing the recordset if it isn't 
           'going to be needed further on. 
           tmLogin.Enabled = true
        Else
           MsgBox "User ID and Password didn't match!", vbCritical, "ERROR LOGIN"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The timer event will only start to fire once this sub has exited and no other code is running.

Comment: Thanks loads! I understand your precise clarification... It's such a great help... I tried datLogin.Recordset.MoveFirst n the false statement of boolLoggedIn. How can I close the recordset?

Comment: I'm glad my answer was of help to you. I am not sure what datLogin is, but I am assuming that the Recordset is an ADODB.Recordset. If that is the case you just call Recordset.Close.

Comment: that is DATACONTROL sir, not ADODB. I have another question sir that I have posted a couple of hour ago. I tried to clarify it more and there's also a screenshot of my tables and frmLogin. The title is **Question about Timer Control in VB6**. Please help me, I just want it to be a rule to resolve the further problems that I might encounter. Thanks in advance sir!

Comment: Ah, ofcoure, I should have guessed that from the name. I am not familiar with that control however, so I'm not sure when the control would normally close the recordset, perhaps when the form is unloaded. But I don't see the harm in closing it earlier if it doesn't cause any problems.